# Javascript can not set value inside of Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I refer below example,

http://jsfiddle.net/rHDh9/

In example , if you click anywhere inside of textarea and if you click to button , it gets button value and sets to textarea where mouse clicked.

**My question:**

If i use below textarea , when i click to button , input value sets to textarea where mouse clicked.

```
<div id="100000000">

<input id="insertPattern" type="button" value="insert pattern" />
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="aboutme">insert some text into this string</textarea>

 </div>
```

However if i use below Html.TextArea , if i click to button , input value never sets to Html.Textarea where mouse clicked.

```
<div id="100000000">

    <input id="insertPattern" type="button" value="insert pattern" />
    @Html.TextArea("editor", new { @class = "ckeditor", @id = "aboutme" })

</div>
```

Why it works for textarea and not work for Html.TextArea on button click ?

Where i miss exactly ?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `@Html.TextArea("editor", new { @class = "ckeditor", @id = "aboutme" })` instead of this you could provide rendered HTML.

Comment: Please provide generate html to resolve the issue

Comment: thanks for answers. @dfsq how come , what do i need to change ?

Comment: Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/rHDh9/1/ after implement your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CKEDITOR, you have to set values for text area like this.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['#aboutme'].setData('insert some text into this string');
```

Comment: how can i get where mouse clicked position(selection)in ckeditor thanks because i want to set value where i clicked

Comment: var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;                            var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ]

Comment: may you please edit code according to #aboutme id because if i write editor1 it does not work thanks i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined  exception

Comment: if i try  var x = CKEDITOR.instances["aboutme"].getSelection().getRanges[0];
            alert(x); , alert displays undefined

Comment: Ultimately you want to insert text where exactly the mouse points right. This piece of code do that. CKEDITOR.instances['aboutme'].insertText("insert some text into this string");

Comment: thanks your answer best i will accept it as best answer please answer also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510628/javascript-ckeditor-get-mouse-click-position thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `@id` when constructing your TextArea (or any form element, for that matter). Just use `id = "aboutme"`.

Comment: What does your DOM look like once it renders? More specifically, what are the differences between straight-up HTML and your MVC-generated one?

Comment: I am using ckeditor and if i give class name as ckeditor , everything is ok however if i click to button , button value can never set to ckeditor text

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when editor was inside a **container displayed with animation** (modal, animation...)

So, i solved the problem like this :

```
var _objEditor = null;
function show_editor_control(){
    $("#main_container").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300);
    setTimeout(initialize_editor,300);
}

function initialize_editor(){
    if(_objEditor!=null) {_objEditor.destroy();};
    CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id');
    _objEditor =CKEDITOR.instances["textarea_id"];
}
```

and for now, it works...