# Javascript Ckeditor Get Mouse click position

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, selection

I am using Ckeditor

**View:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>


<input id="insertPattern" type="button" value="insert pattern" />

@Html.TextArea("editor", new { @class = "ckeditor", id = "aboutme" })
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {

$('input#insertPattern').click(function () {

var txtarea = document.getElementById("aboutme");
var selection = txtarea.getSelection().getStartElement().getOuterHtml();

alert(selection);


}});
```

If i click to buton , i can not alert selection number of mouse click in Html.TextArea in Ckeditor.

**Error:**

In this part of javascript code

```
var selection = txtarea.getSelection().getStartElement().getOuterHtml();
```

I get below error,

uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Where i miss ? How can i get selection of mouse click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you want to insert text where exactly the mouse points right. This piece of code do that.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['aboutme'].insertText("insert some text into this string");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not working with the editor

```
CKEDITOR.instances["editorID"].getSelection().getStartElement().getOuterHtml();
```

From your comments, you want to use

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml

Comment: thanks for help , it gets text value of ckeditor.How can i get mouse selected position and set any value there ?

Comment: CKEDITOR has methods to insert text/html

Comment: var x = CKEDITOR.instances["aboutme"].getSelection().getRanges[0];
            alert(x); alert displays undefined where i miss how can i get selected position ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: As instance , if ckeditor has value like "My Text" . If i click between My and Text after that i want to set value between My and Text so i need to selection position of mouse click how can i do this thanks

Comment: WOW, read the documentation or read about the plugins. The tutorials show you how to do this stuff!